# arranging row of data frame by rownames

Tags: r

I have a output summary like below

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

No i want that the row "N" should be 1st row after header then all rows should come after as it is.
i have tried many solution like arranging, sorting but none of it is working.
the requirement is  N should come first
it should be like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUErU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` to find the row with *n* and `rbind` like:

```
i <- match("n", x$row_labels)
#i <- which("n" == x$row_labels) #Alternative - also for for more than one hit

rbind(x[i,], x[-i,])
#x[c(i, seq_len(nrow(x))[-i]),] #Alternatie
#  row_labels y
#6          n 6
#1          a 1
#2          b 2
#3          c 3
#4          d 4
#5          e 5
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(row_labels=c(letters[1:5],"n"), y=1:6)
```